# Different response length on public IP than on local

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, x-ray

I streaming JSON to browser using [x-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray) scraper:

```
app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {
  // other code
  var stream = x(siteUrl, site.item, site.params)
            .paginate(site.paginate)
            .stream();

  stream.pipe(res);
  // other code
});
```

And I catch it with ajax onprogress event like below:

```
$.ajax('/scrape', {
        xhrFields: {
            onprogress: function (e) {
                console.log(e.currentTarget.response.length); // here is problem

                // other code       
            }
        }
    }
```

And everything here works well on localhost but when I run it through public IP the responses are **randomly** cut and it looks for example like that (in other words I can't handle response properly because json is cut):

```
  {
    "title": "Some Title",
    "link": "http://some...
```

Comment: The `progress` event is triggered while the download is in progress, not just when it's done. It's used to update a progress bar with the fraction of the download.

Comment: When you access localhost, the download is so fast that it never runs during intermediate states, only when the download is done. But on a public IP it goes through the network and is slower.